# android:clickable="true" mean's that it's not clickable?

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView with some custom sections in it. Each section has it's own header View. I want the elements in the list to be clickable, but obviously do not want the section headers to be clickable. So in the xml for the section headers I added `android:clickable="false"`.

When debugging I noticed that the section headers were still responding to my `setOnItemClickListener()`. Then I tried setting `android:clickable="true"` in the XML. And sure enough, the section header views no longer respond to the clicks...

So what is the deal here? Why is it that setting `clickable` = `true` telling it that it is **NOT** clickable? Am I misunderstanding something here? Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

If I set that `clickable="false"` at the bottom, then this view begins to respond to the `setOnItemClickListener()`...

Comment: Can you add the code from your adapter too?

Comment: I am having the same issue and I haven't added any custom onClick listeners.

Comment: try to use viewholder in custome adapter and give clickevents in your adapter class..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743179/click-event-not-working-on-button-in-listview-item/27743279#27743279

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you set the `OnItemClickListener`, the event `onItemClicked` will only be called if the child of the `ListView` does not have the `OnClickListener` set. Setting clickable to true will provide the child view (in this case your `TextView`) with an empty `OnClickListener`. Since the `TextView`'s `OnClickListener` is set the `OnItemClickListener` will not be called.

Comment: I've been trying to experiment with understanding your explanation but I'm not having any luck. Can you show some basic example code that will prove what you are saying is correct? Perhaps I'm just not understanding it...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not write `android:clickable="true"` when it was a child of the list item view. If you have a selector for the `listitem`, just `setbackground` on the root tag.