# Trouble catching onClick event from listview

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, listactivity, simplecursoradapter

I'm asking my user for a postcode via an editText then i use a button to fetch and display store locations in a listView using a simpleCursorAdapter.

Now i want to be able to launch a new activity by selecting an item in the listView and passing along some string information.

I can't get the onClickListener to register my clicks.

Is it because i'm using an Activity instead of a ListActivity?

I'd rather have both the input (the EditText) and the results (ListView) both in the same activity.

activity_pcentry:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/enter_post" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPostCode"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search_button"
        android:onClick="DoPostSearch" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

stockrow_group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/branch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/telephone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" >
    </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

PostCodeEntryActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;    

public class PostCodeEntryActivity extends Activity{

        private MyDatabase stockistsDB;
        public EditText enteredCode;
        private ListView listView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_pcentry);
            stockistsDB = new MyDatabase(this);
        }


        public void DoPostSearch(View v) {

            enteredCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPostCode);
            String postalCode = enteredCode.getText().toString();
            Cursor results = stockistsDB.getStockistsFromPostCode(postalCode);

            if (results != null && results.getCount() > 0) {
                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                        R.layout.stockrow_group,
                        results, new String[]{"fld_BranchName","fld_PostCode","fld_Tel"},
                        new int[]{R.id.branch,R.id.post,R.id.telephone},
                        0);

                listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        Toast.makeText(PostCodeEntryActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(PostCodeEntryActivity.this, "No results found, please check your postcode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post `stockrow_group.xml`

Comment: My mistake, should have had it in from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have any clickable elements on the rows themselves? Please post the XML from R.layout.stockrow_group.

If you have buttons on that layout for example you might need to add the following to those buttons:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

This will make sure the click on the list item is not getting blocked by the clickable item on the row itself.

**The actual solution:**

Do not make the rows of the listview clickable. This will "eat" up the click event by registering an empty click handler. Remove the following line from the rows of the list view:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: Not at the moment, but the plan is to add an imagebutton into the rows and launch maps. I've added the missing xml above.

Comment: What happens if you remove `android:clickable="true"` from the LinearLayout in stockrow_group?

Comment: You know it really is the little things. Thanks very much. Doing a quick search it seems that android:clickable="true" registers an empty onClickListener. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894815/android-androidclickable-true-means-that-its-not-clickable) for more.

Comment: No problem. I have updated my answer with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement `AdapterView.onItemClickListener` in your activity`
2. Change

   `listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()`

   To

   `listView.setOnItemClickListener(this)`
3. Add unimplemented methods

Comment: I'm pretty sure i tried this previously, but I'll give it another go.

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't fire. Nothing registering in debug mode either. Could my editText be holding focus?