# Click event not working on button in listview item

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view, custom-lists

I am using a custom `Listview` with `Custom views` as list elements, each list item is a separate `Custom view`. The problem which I am facing is , click event on button in 1st item of ListView is not getting fired when we click on it. After clicking on it if we click somewhere else in the screen the click event get fires. I am not able to find the solutions for it and I am struggling with it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Updated with code: Here is the getview method

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (position == 0)
        {
            convertView = this.context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.home_hero_container, null);
            this.heroSection = convertView.FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.heroContainer);
            this.setHeroCard();
        }
        else
        {
            convertView = (View)GetItem(position - 1);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

`GetItem` returns CustomView. 1st item will be the hero layout, after that all the `Customviews` will be added to `Convertview`. Click event is not working on the 1st item after hero.

**Update with my answer:**
Instead of assigning `Customview` directly on to `Convertview` I inflated a `FrameLayout` and add `Customview` to `FrameLayout`. Now I don't have click issue.

Comment: Can you please post some codes ?

Comment: post code and logcat if you errors

Comment: Try using ViewHolder in your CustomAdapter, This will give Guaranteed click at appropriate position

Comment: Where you are setting click listener ?

Comment: Click listener will be set inside custom view class itself.

Comment: Yes @AdityaVyas-Lakhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it will work

```
       public class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<ContactInfo> mlist;
Context mcontext;


 public BluetoothChatadpter(Context context,ArrayList<ChatInfo> mchtlist) {      
    mlist =  mchtlist;
    mcontext = context;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int postion) {
    return mlist.get(postion);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup viewgroup){
        View view = null;
        if(convertview == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactrow, null);

            ContactHolder holder = new ContactHolder();

            holder.txtviewfirstname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
            holder.txtviewphone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
            holder.chkselected = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.check);

            setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // to open the selected file in resp

              // do your work here
             }});


chkselected .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// Toast.makeText(context,// "checked is clicke="+pos, 12).show();
        if (chkselected.isChecked())          
                   {            

                    // do your work here
        } else {

 // do your work here                               
        }
    }
});



        view.setTag(holder);

    }
        else{
            view = convertview;
        }
        ContactHolder holder2 = (ContactHolder) view.getTag();
        holder2.txtviewfirstname.setText(list.get(position).firstname);
        holder2.txtviewphone.setText(list.get(position).phonenumber);
        holder2.chkselected.setChecked(list.get(position).selected);
        return view;
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<ContactInfo> mlist;
Context mcontext;


 public BluetoothChatadpter(Context context,ArrayList<ChatInfo> mchtlist) {      
    mlist =  mchtlist;
    mcontext = context;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int postion) {
    return mlist.get(postion);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup viewgroup){
        View view = null;
        if(convertview == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactrow, null);

            ContactHolder holder = new ContactHolder();

            holder.txtviewfirstname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
            holder.txtviewphone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
            holder.chkselected = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.check);

            holder.chkselected.setOnCheckChangeListener(new CheckchangeListener() );



        view.setTag(holder);

    }
        else{
            view = convertview;
        }
        ContactHolder holder2 = (ContactHolder) view.getTag();
        holder2.txtviewfirstname.setText(list.get(position).firstname);
        holder2.txtviewphone.setText(list.get(position).phonenumber);
        holder2.chkselected.setChecked(list.get(position).selected);
        return view;
    }

    class CheckchangeListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener {


        public CheckchangeListener() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub



        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isChecked) {
                 // do your work here

            } else {
                 // do your work here

            }


        }
    }



   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to set onClick event in your Custom adapter and if you have time then check this tutorial for reference - http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.it/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html