# Clicking a scroll view

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a scroll view that has a `Linearlayout` child and this `linearlayout` has a `drawingview`.

the problem : I tried almost all the available answers on this topic and none of them worked, I cant understand why click is not fired for (scrollview, linear layout and even drawingview).

note : I tried setting on click for each of the three and none worked.

the  xml code:

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@id/scrollview"
android:clickable="true"
>

<LinearLayout
android:setorientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@id/linear"
android:clickable="false">


<Customview
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@id/draw"
android:clickable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: btw whats your ide eclipse?

Comment: @Charuka its android studio.

Comment: why you use `setorientation` isn't that `android:id="@id` trows you an error cuz it's not `android:id="@+id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your `ScrollView` ,`layout_height` is wrapped! and for  children you gave `match_parent` i doubt your view won't even display. Isn't it?

Then no idea why you use `setorientation` and `android:id="@id/draw"` instead of `android:orientation` and `android:id="@+id`

If you want to check scrolling works use

```
   scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                Log.d("TAG", "onScrollChanged: ");
                // DO SOMETHING WITH THE SCROLL COORDINATES
            }
        });
```

You are using unnecessary attributes check this example :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8768"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView

        android:id="@+id/scrollIndicatorDown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#823">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/first_child"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="#900"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="#000"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/web_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:background="#987"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you write an `onClickListner` to the id `linear_layout` it just work normally!

---

**Answer** :The child Views of your `ScrollView` are consuming the click events you do on the `ScrollView`.

The solution to this problem is to set the `onClickLIstener` to the immediate child of the `ScrollView`(It's child).

So according to my example if i want to find out the `ScrollView` onClick i write my listener to its child.

```
 scrolChild =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.first_child) ;


        scrolChild .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this, "You Clicked Me OH yeaaaaa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Read here when you need androidclickable-true [android:clickable="true" mean's that it's not clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894815/androidclickable-true-means-that-its-not-clickable)

This is my activity

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ScrollView scrollView;

    private LinearLayout scroolChild;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web);

        scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollIndicatorDown);
        scroolChild =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.first_child) ;


        scroolChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked Me OH yeaaaaa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                Log.d("TAG", "GotAScrollChanged: ");
                // DO SOMETHING WITH THE SCROLL COORDINATES
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: these are typing mistakes but I have them correctly , I didnt copy paste them I typed them , now how I set on click listener to the scroll view please.

Comment: @Hasan B.T use my examaple  try it if it works then *compere*  then you will learn that's your exercise :))

Comment: where does the custom view go?

Comment: @Hasan B.T its just an example that i added cuz your view was wired i added what you want as answer at the bottom

Comment: @Hasan B.T if you want to get the click of scroll view , use it's first child write an onClick to that one and you are good to go :))

Comment: I did what you said , I set on click to the very first child and nothing happened.

Comment: @Hasan B.T are you sure ? then add a `android:clickable="true"` to that view and see but its unnessarory

Comment: @Hasan B.T I posted my activity class as well and i used my xml that i show you in the answer if it does not work tell me

Comment: now my scroll view is found in a frame layout not in linear layout like you did I dont know if that changes anything?

Comment: @Hasan B.T indeed ! its problamatic,I recommend not to use the FrameLayout at all(for scrol child), since it is just a useless container,use a linear layout in this scenario

Comment: @Hasan B.T  No wait if its outside i don't think thats a problem, is a problem when it act as a child of ScrollView .. I am saying it again it only problamatic if it comes under ScrollView as a child but as a parent its fine

Comment: I appreciate the time you gave me to explain, all your explanation is clear and perfect and I discovered that as you said the first child is the one that can be set to on click, but I also discovered that if the first child of scrollview is drawing view it is not being clciked.

Comment: @Hasan B.T I dunno what view you use. you have not given any detail.If it is a problem put a linear layout again as the  child and add your whatever the drawing view inside it as a child.problem solved!

Comment: If it helps you can consider of accepting the answer XOXO

Answer (score 0):

You have set android:clickable="false" for both make it true it will work for you

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@id/scrollview"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
    android:setorientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@id/linear"
    android:clickable="true">


    <Customview
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@id/draw"
    android:clickable="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: set on click only for custom view