# Click event never trigger in ScrollView

Tags: android, onclick, scrollview, onclicklistener

I want to trigger click event in ScrollView.

I take this [Clicking a scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524820/clicking-a-scroll-view) as reference, but it did not work...
I also tried to set all children of ScrollView to be unclickable, but it still not work.

That is part of my Layout.

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/draw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

That is part of my code to set listener.

```
    scroller = ((Activity)c).findViewById(R.id.draw);
    scroller_child = ((Activity)c).findViewById(R.id.frame);

    scroller_child.setOnClickListener(new FrameLayout.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onclicked trigger");
        }
    });

    scroller.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            Log.d("TAG", "scroll");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the set a onClickListener on scrollView :

```
scroller.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            // do what you want 
        }

    });
```

And don't forget to set set the `clickable=false` attribute to each and every child of the `ScrollView` for the `onClickListener` to work on `ScrollView`.